# Should I have closed "Why does Tor Browser use Firefox?" as a question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I've just seen [Why does Tor Browser use Firefox?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/12106/71) pop up in the Low Quality Posts queue and marked it as too broad. After having second thoughts I went back to have a second look.

[canonizing ironize](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/12737/canonizing-ironize) not only gave a good answer, but also edited down the original question (which was a ramble) into concise & relevant query. Seeing them together I think: should I reopen the question?

What do the rest of you think? I see a few answers:

- Leave it closed.
- Reopen it.
- Ask for the question to be expanded before reopening.
- Ask [canonizing ironize](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/12737/canonizing-ironize) to submit as a new question.

I don't know if it really need expansion, but y'all could argue otherwise. As for submitting as a new question, I'm only thinking that it might be more "fair" for the person who actually formatted the sensible question to reap the benefit of any upvotes it earns.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer completes the question.
The question might be short, but I think the answer is good.
So I vote for reopening it..